# Articles in the song of the Beatles

Tags: articles, lyrics, songs

Why there’s no articles in the phase of the song Blackbird?

> Blackbird singing in the dead of night

Would it be more correct to use articles before “Blackbird” and “Night”?

Comment: Song lyrics, newspaper headlines and advertising copy do what they want to obtain the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you. But what about poems? Could I miss an article in my poem, for example?

Comment: ...and poetry, banners, slogans...But as they say, you need to know the rules before you can break them to good effect.

Comment: Also, *dead of night* is an expression, so no 'correcting'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dead of night](https://www.lexico.com/definition/the_dead_of_night) is a common idiom.

He *seems* to be addressing the blackbird, so no definite article is required.

As Weather Vane says, it's a lyric: it might not bear close scrutiny.

Comment: Indeed, *Blackbird singing in the dead of night / Take these broken wings and learn to fly / All your life / You were only waiting for this moment to arise.* The **blackbird** seem to represents a person.

Answer (score 2):

Try singing it that way. Songs have different grammatical rules, which, basically, there are no grammatical rules in songwriting. Songs have to first sound good, the tones of the words. Second, they have to tell a story, and be understood. This means sometimes songs have colloquialisms - "I ain't superstitious," "gimme five" or things like that, common language rules in songs.

The more salient reason here, though, in this song, is that the narrator/singer is addressing the blackbird directly, and giving advice directly. So to use articles like 'the' or 'a' doesn't make sense.

Tangentially, McCartney, who wrote the song himself, without Lennon, has explained in many interviews, easily found, that Blackbird was addressed to young black women, since 'bird' in British slang means girl, chick. So it was a song of encouragement to black women, and blacks in general, during the struggles of civil rights.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).